# Must I Unlock Treasure Maps Before I Can Get New Treasure Maps Via Canvassing / Tag Mode?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

Do I have to unlock the treasure map feature on my own game card before I can receive new treasure maps from other people via Canvassing / Wifi Tag Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You can receive and use treasure maps as soon as you are able to Canvass for Guests at the Quester's Rest in Stornway.

If you receive a treasure map (whether through canvassing or the normal quest in Zere Rocks), you can share it through canvassing as soon as you have beaten that treasure map's boss.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can even go to a friend's world and complete a grotto there to receive a map